# R - Boxplot loop that counts outliers

Tags: r, loops, boxplot

I have been trying to work on this for a while now and I can not figure it out.

9.write a loop which samples the data (using rnorm()), makes the boxplot, and counts the outliers. Keep a running total of how many outliers and divide by total number of data points to estimate the probability.

My data consists of 200 samples and 7 variables

```
x1    x2    x3   x4   x5    x6      GC
```

I tried the following:

```
outlier <- function(dt, var) {
  var_name <- eval(substitute(var),eval(dt))
  na1 <- sum(is.na(var_name))
  m1 <- mean(var_name, na.rm = T)
  par(mfrow=c(3, 2), oma=c(0,0,3,0))
  boxplot(var_name, main="With outliers")
  outlier <- boxplot.stats(var_name)$out
  mo <- mean(outlier)
  var_name <- ifelse(var_name %in% outlier, NA, var_name)
  boxplot(var_name, main="Without outliers")
  title("Outlier Check", outer=TRUE)
  na2 <- sum(is.na(var_name))
  cat("Outliers identified:", na2 - na1, "n")
  cat("Propotion (%) of outliers:", round((na2 - na1) / sum(!is.na(var_name))*100, 1), "n")
  cat("Mean of the outliers:", round(mo, 2), "n")
  m2 <- mean(var_name, na.rm = T)
}

outlier(banknotes, GC)
```

Comment: So... what did you get with your code? What was the problem?

Comment: Nice exercise.  My compliments to your professor.

Comment: I actually got this to work ! Idk what i was doing wrong earlier. :)

Comment: can you share sample data?